# Angular Material datepicker is not working when touchUi is true and action buttons are in use

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w91zpi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-actions-example.html

Set the touchUi on and try to run the example, I mean make the screen smaller --> action buttons are outside of the picker content. Have you any idea how to fix that?
[image]